# setting initial value in combobox in vb

Tags: vb6, combobox

I got a combobox that is populated from a access database. How can I add an item say "all" to the list got from the database and then display it as the first value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After binding it. You can quiet easy do this:

```
cb.Items.Insert(0,"ALL")
```

Liked said in the comment. Do this:

```
Private Sub fview_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
    Timer1.Enabled = True 
    Timer1.Interval = 1000 
    cenNum.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList 
    cenNum.Items.Insert(0, "All") 'adding all to combo  
   fData() 'function populating the combo from database
    cenNum.SelectedIndex=0 'The new line
end sub
```

Comment: Thank you. That adds all to the combobox. How now can I make it one of those items like all to display as the form loads rather than displaying with ititial item being blank and I just have to select from the drop down

Comment: I am not following you. Can you please show some code in your question?

Comment: Here is code that handles form load. `Private Sub fview_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        cenNum.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        cenNum.Items.Insert(0, "All") 'adding all to combo
        fData() 'function populating the combo from database
    End Sub` How can I make one of the items to be displayed by default as the form load. As of now the combox default values as for loads is blank which is not what am looking for

Comment: @ken : remember to upvote if you think the answer is good. It gives us all warm-fuzzy feelings

Comment: @ken  put this before the end sub. cb.ListIndex = 0

Comment: @MarkJ ListIndex was not recognised but I changed it to `Me.comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0` and it giving me lots of smile now. Thanks to you. I had almost given up. @Arion the answer is perfect. It is an answer to the greatest percentage that's why i give the vote

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the record source of the combox box to

```
 SELECT "All" AS Author_name  FROM Author
 UNION SELECT Author_name FROM Author
```

for example